# UIVIew subclass object becomes mysteriously nil in tabbar app

Tags: iphone, null, uitabbarcontroller

Hola caballeros,  I am stumped, mystified, and worse yet, stymied: in my first tab bar project I have an object that is instance of a subclass "BarGraph of UIView, which I've used before without trouble.  In this project I do an alloc-init in the viewDidLoad method of the second viewController, graphViewController.  This sets up the BarGraph.  The data which is read in is displayed properly by that object.

The trouble comes when I use a tab to go to a different viewControler where I add to the data.  I see the change in the appropriate mutable array.  AOK.  But when I come back to the other tab, the data displayed by BarGraph is the same as before.  After some checking, I found that the BarGraph object had become NULL:

```
NSLog(@"barGraph:%@", barGraph)
```

gives "null".  All my attempts to fix fail.  I see only one alloc-init for this object and no deallocs.  These I tracked with NSLog's.  Too weird.  I await your advice.

**Edited to add**

Here is my interface:

```
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController { 
BarGraph *barGraph; 
int foo; 
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) BarGraph *barGraph; 
@property (assign) int foo; 

- (void) updateDisplay; 

@end
```

*** from epsilon2.7 aka Jim Carlson: 
*** Below is where I instantiate BarGraph in GraphViewController.m. I added one line "foo = 100;" to see if the problem has to do with all ivars or just barGraph.  Alas, both foo and barGraph "forget" their values when tabbing away and then tabbing back.  I very much appreciate the feedback (and the kindness to a newb).

```
@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize barGraph, foo;

- (XTabAppDelegate *) theDelegate {
    return (XTabAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}

....

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"BARGRAPH: alloc-init");
    barGraph = [[BarGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 118, 289, 110)];
    foo = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:barGraph];
    [self updateDisplay];
}

....

@end
```

Interface for app delegate, where the data graphed is stored:

```
    @interface XTabAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *tabBarController;

    LogViewController *logViewController; // good
    GraphViewController *graphViewController; // bad

    Log *currentLog; // data stored here
}

...
@end
```

The data in `currentLog` persists (`NSLog` confirms this in GraphViewController), and I push that data into barGraph with the following code in GraphViewController:

```
    -(void) updateBarGraphForDay { 
        Log *theLog = [self theDelegate].currentLog;
        barGraph.data = theLog.log;  // main data stored in the theLog.log
        foo += 1;
}
```

Following up ughoavgfhw's comment, I checked dealloc for both graphViewController and BarGraph, e.g. by inserting an NSLog statement:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"deallocating GraphViewController");
    [barGraph dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Neither is called!

I never see the dealloc.

(2) Below is the code for `didSelectViewController`.  With

```
xtabBarController.delegate = self;
```

in place as the first line of the body of the delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, the method `didSelectViewController` (code below) is executed. If  `[graphViewController updateDisplay]` is not commented out, then (a) I detect a nil barGraph object, (b) I do not see the new data displayed (probably since the relevant message went to a nil object), (c) if I execute `[graphViewController updateDisplay]` manually in `graphViewController` by pushing a button, then the updated info is displayed.

```
// Optional UITabBarControllerDelegate method.
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController      didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"UITabBarControllerDelegate method called");
    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]) {
        NSLog(@"graphViewController selected, graphViewControler = %@", graphViewController);
        [graphViewController updateDisplay];
    }
    ... + similar if statements
}
```

It may be that `[graphViewController updateDisplay]` is called too early, when `graphViewController` is not initialized (???).  I've tried to circumvent these difficulties by implementing `viewWillAppear` in `graphViewController`.  However, `NSLog` informs me that `viewWillAppear` is never called.  Here is the code for `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:TRUE];
    NSLog(@"bb:graphViewController, viewWillAppear called");
    [self updateDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is difficult to debug a problem without any context; please show some relevant code.

Comment: This isn't causing your problem, but change [barGraph dealloc] to [barGraph release] in your dealloc method. You should never call dealloc manually because another object could have a reference to it.

Comment: Where is updateBarGraphForDay being called from? NSLog it to make sure it is being called when you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on, so shot in the dark here.  But, if an object gets released, pointers to that object are not nulled out.  They will only be nulled out if they are explicitly set so.  Further, the fact that you are seeing the old graph indicates to me that the object exists in memory some where.

So, I would guess that you are storing this pointer in some class, for example A.  You have an instance of the class A pointed to by a variable x.  Your barGraph is stored in x.  At some point in the process of moving from one tab to another.  The variable x is reinitialized with a new instance of A.  This new instance hasn't had it's barGraph initialized yet, so is null.  However, the old instance of A still exists somewhere and still has its pointer to barGraph intact.

Answer (score 0):

Another nearly-complete stab in the dark: your BarGraph object is a synthesized property but within that viewController you're accidentally referring to the iVar (`barGraph =`) instead of the property (`self.barGraph =`) so it looks right in that viewController but you're logging the property, which is still nil.

Comment: Here is my interface:
<pre>
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController {

 BarGraph *barGraph;

 int foo;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BarGraph *barGraph;
@property (assign) int foo;

- (void) updateDisplay;

@end
</pre>
I tried (out of desperation+ignorance) commenting out the ivar declaration, just leaving the property declaration.  What is strange is that foo behaves the same way.  I set it to 100 in loadView.  When I go the other tab and then come back, it has the value 0.  This lends support to aepyrus' theory, though I can't find the mistake.  Back to the books.

Comment: I edited your code to include the interface. Please also add the code where you instantiate *barGraph?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"BARGRAPH: alloc-init");
    barGraph = [[BarGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 118, 289, 110)];
    foo = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:barGraph];
    [self updateDisplay];
}

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was suggesting. Change your `barGraph = [[BarGraph...` to **`self.barGraph = [[BarGraph...`**.

Comment: It is proper to use self.barGraph = ..., but this will not effect the outcome. Accessing the property loads the ivar, so it should still show the correct object. Not using the accessor will only prevent change notifications from going out.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand his question, he's accessing the property of one viewcontroller from another viewcontroller, yet in the first viewcontroller he's accidentally setting a local ivar instead of the property. The `self.` isn't a matter of being proper, it literally changes what gets set. If you don't use the `self.` but you only ever access the variable from within the first viewcontroller things look like they work fine. It's the interface to the outside world that's not getting set correctly.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding "self." as you indicated, but the problem remains.  Note similar behavior with the int "foo".  I initialize to 100 in viewDidLoad.  If I tab away and tab back, NSLog reports that foo = 0.   I will think about "self." some more.

Comment: Adding self. does not change what is being set. The default accessors just do any memory management required and set the ivar. Setting the ivar directly just skips the memory management.

Comment: @ughoavgfvw -- Precisely, keeping it from being retained/copied.

Comment: But the value would still be there. It might not be valid anymore (in this case it should since he never released it), but it would not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the GraphViewController is being released and reloaded when you change tabs. When a view controller is not being used, it is released. Then, when it is needed again, a new one is created. Any persistent information should be stored in a model object which is accessed by the controller object. This is basic model-view-controller programming. When your GraphViewController is created, it should connect to a model object and load its information from that, instead of trying to store it itself.

Comment: barGraph reads its data from an instance "currentLog" of a an object "Log" declared in the app delegate. This data persists for the life of the app (and can be modified, saved, and read back in when the app is started again). The data is read by barGraph in "updateBarGraph", a method of GraphViewController. The problem is that after leaving, then returning to the graph tab, barGraph is nil. This fits with your theory, since viewDidLoad is called only once. But I still don't see the fix. I put an NSLog in graphView's dealloc: no sign of a dealloc.

Comment: Try this: Implement didChangeValueForKey: in GraphViewController (make sure you call the super implementation) and NSLog if the key is barGraph. That way you can tell when it is changing. If you set a breakpoint on it, you can see what is calling it also.

Comment: Will do and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

The various NSLog's did indeed lead to the source of the badness: in IB I had put a second referencing connection from "Tab Bar Controller" to "Tab App Delegate".  This was the cause of the double initialization of GraphViewController, namely, the initialization that occurred BEFORE [[GraphViewController alloc] initWith … ] was called.

There remains one problem.  I had added the bad IB connection in order to make the following fire: didSelectViewController:viewController, implemented in the app delegate. Should I ask in new thread?

Comment: Why was that connection causing a double initialization? It should work fine.

Comment: I wish I understood:-(.  The current situation is that the app is working except that a tab doesn't update it when it is selected.  If I add the code (1) xtabBarController.delegate = self; in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, then barGraph reports itself as being nil.  I seem to be stuck on the horns of a dilemma.  With the code (1), didSelectViewController is called, but barGraph and other variables do not behave.  Without the code, the view which one tabs into is not updated without manual intervention.

Comment: Can you post the didSelectViewController method?